# How to avoid strange page breaks in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, classicthesis, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

**Problem**

In the PDF for my PhD I get a lot of very strange page breaks in the middle of the page in the bibliography section (see below)

[image]

**Setup**

I write my PhD in *pandoc markdown*. I then convert the pandoc markdown into *tex* by using `pandoc` and `pandoc-citeproc` together with the latex [ClassicThesis](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis?lang=de) template (basically I place the pandoc variables between the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` commands).

The pandoc command looks like this:

```
pandoc  --latex-engine=xelatex -t latex \
--bibliography=$HOME/Promotion/Arbeitsordner/Dissertation/dissertation.bib \
--template=$HOME/Promotion/Output/template_test.tex \
--verbose \
--toc \
--toc-depth=3 \
--variable=tof \
--number-sections \
--chapters \
${FILES[*]} \
--from markdown+link_attributes+raw_tex+multiline_tables \
-o dissertation_test.tex
```

In the output tex file the area where the page break happens in the PDF on the screenshot looks like this:

```
\hypertarget{ref-dewaard2008modeling}{}
De Waard, Anita, and Joost Kircz. 2008. ``Modeling Scientific Research
Articles - Shifting Perspectives and Persistent Issues.'' In \emph{Proc.
ELPUB2008 Conference on Electronic Publishing}, 234--45.

\hypertarget{ref-dewaard2006abcde}{}
de Waard, Anita, and Gerard Tel. 2006. ``The ABCDE Format. Enabling
Semantic Conference Proceeding.'' In \emph{Proceedings of the First
Workshop on Semantic Wikis -- From Wiki To Semantics}, edited by Max
Völkel and Sebastian Schaffert. Budva, Montenegro.

\hypertarget{ref-denning1995acm}{}
Denning, Peter J., and Bernard Rous. 1995. ``The ACM Electronic
Publishing Plan.'' \emph{Communications of the ACM} 38 (4): 97--109.
doi:\href{https://doi.org/10.1145/205323.205348}{10.1145/205323.205348}.
```

As you can see there is no special character or unnormality that gives a hint why the page breaks happens (the fact that 'First' is the last word of the line is just a coincident of this examples, in the case of other strange page breaks in the bibliography this is not the case).

I turn the tex file into a pdf by using *xelatex*: `xelatex dissertation_test.tex`

**Question**

Does someone have an idea for why such page breaks happen and how I can avoid this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you reduce `dissertation_text.tex` to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: it's not straightforward to avoid page breaks in bibliography items that are more than three lines long.  three-line (or fewer) can be suppressed by setting both `\widowpenalty` and `\clubpenalty` to 10000.  the broken item in your case is four lines long.  there is a `samepage` environment that perhaps could be edited into the file manually, or patched into the code for formatting the bibliography.  i have no idea whether this is possible at the `pandoc` level.

Comment: Start reducing... Compile this chapter only, remove classicthesis, check other document classes. Is there a reason for not using biblatex to manage your bibliography? This is just some formatted text, right? What happens when you shuffle those references?